# Selecting similar keyframes?

Tags: animation

I have a rig that is animated. It is cluttered with a lot of keyframes for its scale, despite the fact that this is completely irrelavent.

I would like to delete all keyframes pertaining to the scale values across all of my bones at once. I can't seem to figure this out—presumably, selecting all "scale keyframes" in the dope sheet or something of that sort would work, but I don't know how to do that.

Any advice?

Comment: This would be a nice feature. Sadly, I wasn't able to figure it out either. The only way I knew to do it was to go into the Dope Sheet with the Only Show Selected button turned off, manually uncollapse all of the channel headers to expose the channels beneath, then multiselect all the scale channels, and then right-click to get the Channel Context menu, and choose Delete Channels. Not an ideal solution, I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open a graph editor, then in the search option type in scale:
[image]
If you want to do this for all bones, unhide them and select all, if you want to do this for all objects in the scene, Click the show only selection icon. With your mouse over the list of scale keyframes press a untill they are all selected and x -> delete.

Comment: Eureka! Don't know how I missed this for so long. Thanks! :)